# How to sort an array of strings of zeros and ones?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to sort an array of ints by it's binary form. for example if i have `{1,2,3}` i must convert them to binary then sort them based on how many `1` each has, if the number only has one `1` then it is number 1 and then comes the number that has two `1`s in its binary form and so on.

i tried to use the following two methods but i couldn't do them due to errors and i don't understand. i searched all stackoverflow but can't figure it out, i am stuck for our here in this problem.

```
public static int[] xx = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 87, 8, 9, 7, 5, 24, 58, 63, 10, 11, 87, 20, 22, 90, 14, 17, 19, 21, 18, 24 };

        public string[] ChangeToBinary(int[] data)
        {
            string[] binary = new string[data.Length];
            var i = 0;
            foreach (int d in data)
            {
                string newvalue = Convert.ToString(d, 2);
                binary[i] = newvalue;
                i++;
            }
            return binary;
        }

        public int[] Sort(string[] binaries)
        {
            Array.Sort(binaries, (x, y) => x.Count(z => z == '1') > y.Count(e => e == '1'));
            string[] sorted = binaries.OrderBy(b => b.Count(z => z == '1') > b.Count(e => e == '1'));
        }
```

the two lines inside the `sort` function i know that they are wrong in some point that i dont get can someone tell me how to do it ? i try to say to sort the elements of the array based on the least number of `1`s in the element.

I won;t use both but i put them to show you what i wanted to use.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you're after? `xx.OrderBy(i => Convert.ToString(i, 2).Count(c => c == '1'))` ?

Comment: yes to let the int array become sorted by according to the number of ones it got , i know my code is messy i am just scrathing at first

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: While that may be all that's required, I don't think just the code is as much help as an explanation of what's going wrong with the OP's current code.

Comment: I agree, which is why I didn't just throw it out as an answer.

Comment: You say "because of the errors", can you please post these errors?

Comment: The first error is due to `Array.Sort`, with the code you currently have, is likely to take a `Comparison` delegate which returns an int (-1 is a<b, +1 if a>b, 0 if a=b), not a delegate that returns a bool. You could fix this by just doing: `Array.Sort(..., x.Count(...).CompareTo(y.Count(...)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a help of `Convert` and *Linq* you can easily count `1`s:

```
 int value = ...

 ones = Convert
   .ToString(value, 2)    // Binary representation
   .Count(c => c == '1'); // Count 1's
```

Having this done, let's sort the array:

```
 int[] xx = ...

 int[] sorted = xx
   .OrderBy(value => Convert // criterium: see the code above
      .ToString(value, 2)
      .Count(c => c == '1'))
   .ThenBy(value => value)   // on tie e.g. 0b101 and 0b110 let's use value
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: @ahmed nader: I've split the initial task into *two*: 1st - criterium implementation (how to count `1`s) 2nd: how to sort the array when having criterum implemented.

Comment: okay i understand and it works but i want to ask if i want to add more conditions can i add it in this linq way ? because i may find that some of the numbers has the same number of 1s in it so in this case i will sort those by the decimal for example if 5 and 6 same number of 1s then i will put the 5 before 6

Comment: @ahmed nader: chain conditions with a help of `ThenBy(value => SomeCriterium())`. I've added one `ThenBy` in order to break tie (if two value have same `1` nmber, e.g. `5 == 101b` and `6 == 110b`)

Comment: yes i mean i didnt use linq before if i want to put the condition i told u how to put it ? can i put ifs inside the thenby ? i am first time linq to be honest

Comment: @ahmed nader: you can't put condition within `ThenBy` in a form of `IComparer<T>` or `Comparison<T>` delegate (e.g.`(left, right) => left.CompareTo(right)`); but you can use *mapping* - we provide a criterium (e.g. number of `1`s or item itself) by which we want to order

Comment: thanks alot it is working but i want to ask one more thing sir, i tried to type xx.skip(1) to skip the first value because i dont want to process it but it skips the value 1 not the first value , you know what i mean ?

Comment: @ahmed nader: You have 3 ways to skip: 1. You can `Skip(1)` - skip top `1` (`xx[0]`) items; 2. `Where(value => value != 1)` - skip all items which are equal `1`; 3. Finally, `Where((value, index) => index != 1)` - skip item at 1st position (`xx[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

There are two different approaches to custom sorting:

- You provide a comparison between any two elements. This is what `Array.Sort` takes. The comparison has to return an `int` with a value that's negative, zero or positive to indicate whether the first element is less than, equal to or greater than the second element. (Your lambda expression currently returns `bool` because you're using `>`.)
- You provide a projection from *one* element, and the sort algorithm compares the results of that projection. That's what `OrderBy` does - but the lambda expression you're providing in the `OrderBy` compares the count of one element with the count from the *same* element.

I would suggest using the `OrderBy` approach, because that's much simpler. You're just trying to order by the count, so you just need to count the 1s in the element you're provided, and return that count:

```
string[] sorted = binaries.OrderBy(b => b.Count(z => z == '1')).ToArray();
```

Now your method is meant to return an `int[]` at the moment. Presumably it would convert each binary string back to an `int`. I'd suggest *not* doing that - instead change your `Sort` method to return the sorted `string[]`. You can then perform the conversion in another method, whether that's a separate method or the calling method.

That's the approach I'd take first, as the minimal change to your code - and as a way of understanding what's going on in the `Sort` and `OrderBy` methods. You can then potentially change to order the integers directly without ever directly creating an array of strings, as Dmitry suggests.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for those of us who are just tip-toeing around Linq. More code but remember the linq is looping underneath.

```
 public static int[] xx = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 87, 8, 9, 7, 5, 24, 58, 63, 10, 11, 87, 20, 22, 90, 14, 17, 19, 21, 18, 24 };
        public class MyBinary
        {
            public string BinString { get; set; }
            public int OneCount { get; set; }
            public int OriginalInt { get; set; }
            public MyBinary(string input, int count, int original)
            {
                OriginalInt = original;
                BinString = input;
                OneCount = count;
            }
        }

        private List<MyBinary> SortByOnes(int[] input)
        {
            List<MyBinary> lst = new List<MyBinary>();
            //The following will give a result First ordered by number of ones but also 
            // secondarily the original numbers
            //just a bit of linq
            int[] SortedArray = (from i in input orderby i select i).ToArray();
            List <MyBinary> lstSorted = new List<MyBinary>();
            int index = 0;
            string[] Bin = new string[SortedArray.Count()];
            foreach (int i in SortedArray)
            {
                Bin[index] = Convert.ToString(i, 2);
                 int oneCount = 0;
                foreach (char c in Bin[index])
                {
                    if (c == '1')
                        oneCount += 1;
                }
                //sends the binary string, the count of ones, and the original number
                //to the constructor of MyBinary
                lst.Add(new MyBinary(Bin[index], oneCount, i));
                lstSorted = (from b in lst orderby b.OneCount descending select b).ToList();
                index += 1;
            }
            return lstSorted;
        }
       //To use:
        private void TestSort()
        {
            List<MyBinary> lst = SortByOnes(xx);
            foreach (MyBinary b in lst)
            { Debug.Print($"{b.OneCount}  -  {b.BinString}  -  {b.OriginalInt}"); }
        }
```